# Delete space between combobox and table

Tags: html, combobox, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
            <head>
            <title>就知道</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
            </head>
            <div align="center">
            <body>
            <p align="center"><img src="./img/Logo.jpg" width="70" height="65"></p>
            <form name="form1" method="get" action="?" onsubmit="getValue()">     
            <div align="center" style= "display:inline"><select id="uiSel">
                <option value=" 请输入码"<?php if($resultkeyTag == " 请输入码"){echo 'selected';}?>> 号码</option>
                <option value=" 请输入名"<?php if($resultkeyTag == " 请输入名" OR $resultkeyTag == ""){echo 'selected';}?>> 姓名</option>
            </select></div>
              <div align="center" style= "display:inline"><?php if(empty($_GET['key']))  
              <input style="color:#999;" name="key" type="text" id="Txt" style="height:17px" style="font-size:12px" size="20" style="color:gray" value=" 请输入名"
            <?php } 
             </div>
            <div style="display:inline"><iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src=./localcombodata.php?eventSelected=<?php echo $_GET['key1'] ?>&yearSelected=<?php echo $_GET['keyYearSelected'] ?> width="299″ height="0″ frameborder="no″ scrolling="no″ marginheight="0px" align="top" style="border:0px" marginwidth="0" ></iframe></div>
            <div style= "display:inline"><input type="submit" style="height:24px" style="font-size:13px" value="一下" ></div>
            <input name="key1" type='hidden' id="content" size="1" value="<?php if($_GET['key1'] == ""){echo '全部事';}else{echo $_GET['key1'];} ?>">
            <input name="keyYearSelected" type='hidden' id="inputYearSelected" size="1" value="<?php if($_GET['keyYearSelected'] == ""){echo '全部年份';}else{echo $_GET['keyYearSelected'];} ?>">
            <input name="keyTag" type='hidden' id="contentkeyTag" size="1" value="<?php if($_GET['keyTag'] == ""){echo ' 请输入名';}else{echo $_GET['keyTag'];} ?>">
            </form>
            <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" margin-top="0">
            <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA" >
                          <td width="40">年份</td>
                          <td width="*">事名称</td>
                          <td width="*">姓名</td>
                          <td width="48">性别</td>
                          <td width="58">号码</td>
                          <td width="74">成绩</td>
                         </tr>  
        </table>
        </body>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried many times to delete space between combobox and table but failed.

I didnot use CSS. Main code as above. Thanks! Happy new year.

Comment: I think that the code has some errors, what about posting just the HTML without the PHP code? To do so, load the web page, right-click and select **View page source**

Comment: thank you so much! here you are:  http://shhaiupload.gotoip1.com/betatestindex.php?key=+%C7%EB%CA%E4%C8%EB%D0%D5%C3%FB&key1=%C8%AB%B2%BF%C8%FC%CA%C2&keyYearSelected=%C8%AB%B2%BF%C4%EA%B7%DD&keyTag=+%C7%EB%CA%E4%C8%EB%D0%D5%C3%FB

Comment: Clarifications to the question should be made by editing the question, not in comments. A question should be understandable as-is, without reading comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spacing is caused by the `iframe` element. You can see this e.g. if you first add `form { outline: solid red }` to a style sheet and then, having seen that the form is rather tall, change that to `iframe { outline: solid red }`. Inspecting the document with Firebux shows that the `iframe` element is 150 pixels tall.

As usual, HTML validation is a good tool for spotting many errors, but in this case, the cause of the problems can also be seen by looking at the `iframe` tag is a good text editor:

```
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1"
src=./combodata.php?eventSelected=全部赛事&yearSelected=全部年份
width="299″ height="0″ frameborder="no″ scrolling="no″ marginheight="0px" align="top" 
style="border:0px" marginwidth="0">
```

When a good font is used, you can see that the values of the `width`, `height`, `frameborder`, and `scrolling` attributes all start with the normal Ascii quotation mark `"` but end with `″` (U+2033 DOUBLE PRIME). The latter is not a markup-significant character in HTML, just yet another data character. What this means that browsers won’t stop parsing the attribute value when they encounter that character but proceed to find a matching Ascii quotation mark. So what they get is

```
width="299″ height="
```

followed by `0″` etc., and although the `width` value will actually be parsed as a number `299` (ignoring the rest), the keyword `height` was lost, i.e. no `height` attribute was recognized. Therefore, the default value of 150 (pixels) is used.

The simplest fix is to replace each occurrence of `″` by `"`.

But you should probably try to find out what caused the problem. Perhaps some authoring tool used converted Ascii quotation marks to double prime characters, and in a rather illogical way (converting only the *closing* quotation mark of some attribute value specifications).

Comment: The simplest fix works! thanks Jukka K. Korpela so much!